# Set up database creation/migrations from code for Entity Framework 6 + MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, database-migration

I've previously used NHibernate and Fluent Migrator in projects to create a database (if it didn't already exist) and update the schema through migration scripts.  I'm looking over Entity Framework (6) to do a comparison and I'm having trouble replicating that functionality.

In my `App.config`, I've set up my connection string and db providers.  I then went ahead and created a data model that I would like to be represented as a table in the database.

```
namespace DataModels
{
    public class StoreClient
    {
        public int Id;
        public string DisplayName;

        public StoreClient()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I then went ahead and created a database context.

```
namespace DataModels
{
    public class StoreContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<StoreClient> StoreClients { get; set; }
    }
}
```

On service start I created an instance of `StoreContext` and tried to add and call `db.SaveChanges();`, but this is failing because there is no schema that matches my StoreClient.

My question is simple.  How do I configure my `StoreContext` (or EF in general) to automatically create my database schema, and how do I set it up to migrate when I make changes to that schema?

This seems simple, but my searching around hasn't gotten me anything that looks remotely familiar coming from the NHibernate world.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your db to be created automatically try to put some code in your Application_Start() method.
for example:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<StoreContext, Configuration>());
StoreContext context = new StoreContext();
context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Where Configuration class is created upon automatic migrations are enables in the console. Check out this msdn [demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).
Also i am not shure that your code firs model will work that way. If not try changing your fields with properties.

```
namespace DataModels
{
    public class StoreClient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public StoreClient()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tips.  Where do you configure the migration steps?  I assume it doesn't just implicitly sort it out?

Comment: When you enable migrations it scaffolds for you a configuration class with some functionality in it. All the other things are done automatically I think.